# Constant "division by zero" error in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I have a code that is returning me a "division by zero" error and I can't understand why.
I've looked online but there are little information about it for pine script.

This was the original code

```
z = (x / x + y) * 100
```

that I've since changed it to

```
if x > 0 and y > 0
    z = (x / x + y) * 100
```

but I'm still getting the same error, even though it doesn't make much sense, as I've negated the possibility to divide by zero.

The only post I've found about it says that pine might be seeing this as an integer equation, so since x and y are variables, I've tried to change the script in the following way, but I'm still getting the same error

```
//@version=5
indicator('test')

float x = 0.0
float y = 0.0
float z = if x > 0 and y > 0
    (x / x + y) * 100
else
    z = 0.0

plot(z)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hardcoded value of x as 0 and are not modifying it using x as divisor
So pinescript is assuming that x will be 0 if division happens anytime the condition is true

So just add a dummy x:=x after declaring it and issue will go away

```
float x = 0.0
float y = 0.0
x:=x
float z = if x > 0 and y > 0
    (x / x + y) * 100
```

Comment: Thank you. It's a weird case as the condition should bypass the equation but good to have such an easy solution!

Comment: Condition will baypass the equation but compiler cannot figure it out beforehand, so it is a compiler lever error

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior in Pine, expression in the `if` scope is still checked when you compile code, even though the result of this `if` expression is false. You may use serial numbers (suggested above `x:=x` makes `x` serial value), then this expression will be executed in runtime and return `na`.